# DXA - Publishing configuration for binaries

Tags: dxa, installation

As per the [SDL installation documentation pre-requisites](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-8E88E5AF-4552-40F0-8DB2-FBDBDBA41A11#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-6D3337B6-FC47-479A-A38B-6AF3C53B9A51.xml&docid=GUID-6D3337B6-FC47-479A-A38B-6AF3C53B9A51&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-6D3337B6-FC47-479A-A38B-6AF3C53B9A51) for reference website implementation, publishing must only be done to the database. Does this also include binary item types to be configured with the database as blogs or just other item types (except binaries) and binary metadata in the database?

I am assuming that it is the latter but wanted to check!

Comment: Everything in DB, including binaries, no DB configuration needed as this is already in place.

Comment: everything is in DB and its gets cached in your application for further requests.

Comment: Further to this question, I am just wondering the behavior of DCPs. How those will be separate from pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Nuno's comment, everything is stored in the DB (including binaries). I am positive that I will have additional questions (because of our content delivery customization) but I will post a detailed question later. :). I will close the question.